# Where does this high serverload come from?

Tags: file, static, jetty

We use an embedded jetty server with a bundle with registered resources in the `org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.resources` extensionpoint.

Now when we try to get static data out of it, (small sized mp3, like 30 files) the serverload shoots up to 100%. It's if the jetty server is processing all mp3 files, which is definitly not the way we want.

Is there a way to serve these files static, without loading the server that much?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: How long does it stay at 100%? Have you looked at a thread-dump?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already solved it:

by putting large files into a jar and registering it with org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.resources the request for the file needs extraction out of the jar.

We cut the resources out of the jar and put it in a separate folder, registering the folder itself with the http service and it runs smooth.